# servicio de windows que llama a un proceso en asp.net

Tags: visual-studio, servicio

Hice una pagina web en asp.net, resulta que terminado todo descubrí que necesitabamos realizar una operación todos los días al menos una vez por día. Leyendo e investigando descubrí que lo mejor es crear un Servicio de windows, ya que las páginas necesitan si o si la interacción del usuario.
Estuve haciendo prácticas y logré realizar un servicio de prueba que funcione correctamente
Ahora, la pregunta es como organizo la Solución desde visual studio. 
Digamos, creo dentro de la solucion (donde tengo los proyectos (backend y frontend) de las paginas web) otro proyecto de servicio de windows, luego agrego una referencia al proyecto. Con esto ya es suficiente?

EDITO PARA ACLARAR PREGUNTAS
El sitio esta diseñado en dos capas, uno llamado Clases, y otro llamado web. 
Actualmente, tengo una pagina que solo tiene un botón que dispara un proceso que se encuentra en la capa "Clases" pero que no tiene respuesta ni nada, solo corre, realiza una función y actualiza una base de datos y si es necesario envía un mail. Es decir que no hay intercambio con la web ni nada. Me gustaría que ese proceso se hiciera automáticamente sin la necesidad de entrar al sistema y apretar ese botón todos los días.
Imaginé un servicio de windows, al cual le agregaba la referencia de la capa de Clases, y luego, con un timer llamo a ese proceso. Sería Correcto eso?? En la respuesta que me pasaron mas abajo aparentemente lo que llama es a una pagina web. Es posible hacer algo asi pero con un proceso?

Comment: Si el proyecto no es grande digamos solo tienes los tres proyectos puedes usar la misma solucion,

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes estructurada la lógica de tu backend? ¿Son WebServices (SOAP/REST)? ¿El Servicio Windows estará ejecutándose en el mismo servidor que la Web Application? Dependiendo de esto, tendrás que utilizar alguna de varias alternativas (agregar web references, utilizar Requests http, agregar referencias a dlls, etc.). Alguna de las alternativas va a representar un esfuerzo menor de desarrollo y facilidad de mantenimiento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una vez aclarada la pregunta, tu conclusión es correcta.

Agregas tu proyecto Windows Service a la solución actual (deben quedar tres proyectos).

Al proyecto Windows service le agregas una referencia a tu proyecto de Clases (Class Library).

Desde el timer, haces la llamada al proceso que actualmente invocas desde el botón y listo.

Otra alternativa, sería crear un proyecto de Consola que solo se encargue de invocar el mismo proceso del botón, y dejarlo programado en el Scheduler (Programador de tareas), del sistema operativo.

Esta segunda alternativa tiene la ventaja de que no es necesario ejecutar ningún proceso de instalación del servicio en el equipo.

Comment: gracias amigo... saludos.

Answer (score 3):

No necesitas hacer la referencia de tu proyecto web en tu proyecto servicio de windows, ya que este no estará consumiendo las funciones como tales (no hará referencia al dll). Lo único que necesitas es hacer una llamada web.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");
request.Method = "GET";
String test = String.Empty;
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    test = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
}
```

Respecto a ponerlos en tu misma solución, ya que no hay dependencia real, ya es cuestión de organización del proyecto.

Comment: Hola Amigo, gracias por tu respuesta. Edite mi post original para explicarme mejor, lo que ti me indicas sera posible hacerlo para un proceso?!

Comment: En ese caso ni siquiera necesitas el proyecto web. Como ya lo comentas. lo que necesitas es un proyecto de servicio de windows que ejecute esa acción cada determinado tiempo. Y ahí si, necesitaras agregar la dependencia de proyecto al que llamas clases, para poder acceder a la funcionalidad.

Comment: gracias amigo, saludos.